# check other possibilities PROLOG

Tags: prolog

I want to make a program that tells me the steps I need to take, things to keep in mind are:
from node 1 to other there is a colour (red, brown, yellow) must be in this order, for every step.
Now i am able to go with the color, but the thing is that i dont know how to go back to the last step and choose different node if i cant go ahead.
this is my code:

```
maze_steps(A,B) :-
    first_color(A,B,[]).
 first_color(A,B,Visited):- go(A,B, red, Visited).

 next_color(A,B,Cr,Visited):-
    Cr = red -> go(A,B, brown, Visited);
    Cr = brown -> go(A,B, yellow, Visited);
    Cr = yellow -> go(A,B, red, Visited).
 go(A,B,Cr,Visited):-
    link(A, Cr, X), not(member(X,Visited)),
    ( B = X; next_color(X,B,Cr,[A|Visited])).
```

knowledge base:

```
[![link(b,brown,j).
link(b,red,d).
link(j,red,n).
link(j,brown,l).
link(i,yellow,b).
link(i,yellow,d).
link(i,red,t).
link(d,yellow,j).
link(d,red,k).
link(k,yellow,j).
link(k,red,l).
link(k,brown,r).
link(l,brown,n).
link(l,yellow,p).
link(p,yellow,n).
link(t,brown,d).
link(t,red,k).
link(t,brown,h).
link(g,red,k).
link(r,yellow,l).
link(r,brown,p).
link(r,yellow,s).
link(c,brown,i).
link(c,red,t).
link(c,brown,a).
link(a,yellow,t).
link(a,red,h).
link(a,red,m).
link(h,red,r).
link(h,yellow,e).
link(e,yellow,r).
link(e,brown,s).
link(e,red,f).
link(s,red,p).
link(v,yellow,c).
link(v,brown,a).
link(v,red,m).
link(m,brown,h).
link(m,brown,e).
link(m,yellow,f).
link(f,brown,s).
link(start,red,m).][1]][1]
```

ON CALL 12 IT GOES WITH M, BROWN, H, BUT IT NEVER GOES WITH M, BROWN, E.
WHAT SHOULD I DO IN ORDER TO FORCE PROLOG TO COME BACK AT THIS POINT AND TAKE ANOTHER NODE.

ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED.
[image: trace]

[image: trace]

Answer (score 0):

WELL, thats strange, nobody answered!!!

but i cracked it, its like this,

```
 maze_steps(A,B) :-
    go(A,B,red,[]).

 next_color(A,B,Cr,Visited):-
    Cr = red -> go(A,B, brown, Visited);
    Cr = brown -> go(A,B, yellow, Visited);
    Cr = yellow -> go(A,B, red, Visited).

 go(A,B,Cr,Visited):-   
    (link(X, Cr, A); link(A, Cr, X)),
    (\+(member(A+Cr+X,Visited)), \+(member(X+Cr+A,Visited))),
   ( B = X, write([A+Cr+X|Visited]), write('\n'); next_color(X,B,Cr,[A+Cr+X|Visited])).
```

Problem solved, anyway thanks.